# Moving to next element in a unorder list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

i have a list of images that i want to cycle through using next / previous buttons.  but i'm having real trouble doing it.  so far I've managed to just keep reverting to the first image no matter what image i'm on when i click next link.

the html for the list is ..

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="slider-container">
    <ul class="wineslider">
        <li>
            <img src="assets/img/shop/redwine/bottle.png" alt="1">
            <div class="info">
                <p>I am wine information 1 </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/img/shop/redwine/bottle.png" alt="2">
            <div class="info">
                <p>I am wine information 2</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="assets/img/shop/redwine/bottle.png" alt="3">
            <div class="info">
                <p>I am wine information 3</p>
            </div> 
        </li>
.....

<a href="#" class="previous">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>

</div>

</div>
```

the jquery i've been fiddling around with is

this slides the images if they are clicked on - this bit seems to work okay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wineslider li').bind({
    click: function() {
      $('.wineslider li').stop().animate({'width':'60px'},600);
      $(this).stop().animate({'width':'420px'},600); // Width of slideout box
      $('.info').css('display','block');
    },
});

// Find number of slides
var count   = $('li').length;
//alert(count);

// Set current slide number
var curr    = 1;
ert(curr);



});
```

the next button

```
var active = 0; // starts at zero
var list = $('ul.wineslider');
$("a.next").click(function(event){


event.preventDefault();         // cancel click through
var currentElement = $('.wineslider li');
var i = $(currentElement).index();

currentElement = currentElement.next();
scrollTo(currentElement);  
$('.wineslider li').stop().animate({'width':'60px'},600);
$(currentElement).stop().animate({'width':'420px'},600); // Width of slideout box
$('.info').css('display','block');

});
```

thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

var currentElement is selecting an li but not specified which li. Do something like add a class "selected" for the li that is active. Then you could do current elem = $('.selected')

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that currentElement is a jQuery object containing the collection of all li's. It is not the specific li that is currently selected.

In this case you may want to add a class or something to your current li element so you can get a better handle on it like so.

```
currentElement = $('.wineslider li.current');
nextElement = currentElement.next();
```